# Logging and configuration for .Net core 2.0 console application?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

The following code got the errors. What's the right way to setup logging and configuration management for .Net Core 2.0 console application?

> Error CS1061  'LoggerFactory' does not contain a definition for 'AddConsole' and no extension method 'AddConsole' accepting a first argument of type 'LoggerFactory' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection' to 'System.Action'

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(services);
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var app = serviceProvider.GetService<Application>();
        Task.Run(() => app.Run()).Wait();
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
            .AddConsole() // Error!
            .AddDebug();

        services.AddSingleton(loggerFactory); // Add first my already configured instance
        services.AddLogging(); // Allow ILogger<T>

        IConfigurationRoot configuration = GetConfiguration();
        services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(configuration);

        // Support typed Options
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<MyOptions>(configuration.GetSection("MyOptions")); // Error!

        services.AddTransient<Application>();
    }

    private static IConfigurationRoot GetConfiguration()
    {
        return new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddXmlFile("App.config", optional: true).Build();
    }

    public class MyOptions
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Application
    {
        ILogger _logger;
        MyOptions _settings;

        public Application(ILogger<Application> logger, IOptions<MyOptions> settings)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _settings = settings.Value;
        }

        public async Task Run()
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"This is a console application for {_settings.Name}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of topic: Use `GetSection(nameof(MyOptions))` instead of `GetSection("MyOptions")`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks you might be missing a couple of dependencies:

1. [`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/), which provides the `AddConsole` extension method.
2. [`Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions/), which provides the `Configure<T>` extension method you appear to be missing.

In terms of configuring the services in .NET Core executables, Andrew Lock has a [post](https://andrewlock.net/using-dependency-injection-in-a-net-core-console-application/) on the topic for the first version of .NET Core. Some of this may be out of date now with .NET Core 2's recent arrival, but it's worth a read.

Answer (score 19):

Building upon Kirk Larkins answer (make sure you have the nuget packages installed, `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions`, `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug`) then you can simplify the logging configuration and skip the declaration of the loggerFactory by passing in an `ILoggerBuilder` to `.AddLogging()`:

```
public static IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    //ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
    //  .AddConsole()
    //  .AddDebug();

    serviceCollection
        .AddLogging(opt =>
        {
            opt.AddConsole();
            opt.AddDebug();
        })
        .AddTransient<IFooService, FooService>();

    /*... rest of config */

    var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    return serviceProvider;
}
```